# best practice for change SQL server record automatically, after certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

im currently looking for best practice for my problem ,

i have this table A, for every new record inserted the default value for column **Status** is `Waiting` .
every record need to have a "timer" , in my case its 5 min . If its not set from `Waiting` to `Completed` in 5 minutes , it needs to be `Expired`

example :

```
| No. | Status   |
| --- | -------  |
| 1   | Expired  |
| 2   | Completed|
| 3   | Waiting  |
```

What's the best way to accomplish this ? whether its SQL server approach or C# Net. coding approach.

what i have tried , is making a computed column in SQL Server named `Status_auto` , and then put the logic inside the computed column query to set value based on `Status` and `Create_date`.
It works as intended, but im not sure is it a really good method , since the table is expected to have thousands record and i'm worry about the performance issue later in production because of this computed column

Comment: I don't see any problem with the computed column, if that works for you. You can easily test the expected performance in a test table loading it with millions of rows. An alternative is a SQL Agent job to run and update the status of qualifying rows.

Comment: yeah , but i ended up having 2 status columns and i dont really like it tbh. I was thinking about SQL job too but it needs to run Update query too often ( maybe every 30 sec) , and possibly not gonna update exact 5 minutes per record .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the time that the value was inserted into the table.

Then use a view to calculate the status.

The view looks like:

```
create view v_t as 
    select t.*,
           (case when getdate() > dateadd(minute, 5, waiting_start) and
                      status <> 'Completed'
                 then 'Expired'
                 else status
            end) as actual_status
    from t;
```

No updates or scheduling is needed if this is handled using comparisons.

Comment: thanks  , i will use this as view to inquiry the data . And then update the actual table based on this view to sync the Status.

Comment: @RLHakim . . . And you can schedule that synchronization at a convenient time -- when the server is less busy,.